# print the average of each year from txt.file

Tags: python, python-3.x, average

I need to print the average per year for an assignment. I have the following:
a text file that is like this with over 2000 lines:

```
Unit 42;2017;7.0
Love Your Garden;2011;8.0
Limmy's Show;2010;8.3
Nazi Megastructures;2013;8.0
Omniscient;2020;6.3
Green Frontier;2019;7.4
Los Briceño;2019;8.4
Aftermath;2014;
Sugar;2006;
Beyond Stranger Things;2017;
Men on a Mission;2018;
Click for Murder;2017;
```

As you can see some movies don't have a grade so these need to be ignored
Now i need to output it like this:

```
2000: 1,1111
2001: 2,2222
etc up until 2020
```

Now I made the following code to extract the right parts from the txt file

I tried the following:

```py
file = open("tv_shows.txt", "r", encoding='utf8')
#content = file.read()


result = {}

for line in file:
    year, number = line.split(';')[1], line.split(';')[2]
    if len(number) <3:
        continue
    year = int(year)
    number = float(number)
    try:
        result[year].append(number)
    except KeyError:
        result[year] = [number]

for k, v in sorted(result.items()):
    print('{}: {:.4f}'.format(k, sum(v) / len(v)))
```

it gives me this, which is a lot better, but now it raises a new question for me. How can i remove the redundant zero's in the average numbers.

```
2000: 7.7000
2001: 7.4000
2002: 7.1000
2003: 7.0091
2004: 7.6667
2005: 7.7333
2006: 7.2579
2007: 7.5080
2008: 7.1630
2009: 7.3884
2010: 7.3904
2011: 7.3507
2012: 7.0787
2013: 7.0418
2014: 7.2427
2015: 7.2462
2016: 7.1730
2017: 7.1478
2018: 7.0034
2019: 7.1191
2020: 6.8130
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried. Do you know what `the average` is?

Comment: I updated my code and it raised a new question for me:  How can i remove the redundant zero's in the average numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are *not* allowed to use `pandas`,

```
file = open("tv_shows.txt", "r", encoding='utf8')
years = {}
for a in file:
    _, year, number = a.split(';')
    if len(number) <3:
        continue
    year = int(year)
    number = float(number)
    if year not in years:
        years[year] = [] # Add a new list to the years dict
    years[year].append(number) # Append the current number to the correct list.

avgyears = {}
for year, numberlist in years.items():
    # iterate over the dict, find the mean of each list
    avgyears[year] = sum(numberlist) / len(numberlist)
```

---

The question was edited while I was writing my answer. The modified question asks "How can I remove the redundant zero's in the average numbers?"

The extra zeros are added because you ask Python to format your number to four decimal places. To remove the zeros from the right side of the string, you can simply use [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)

```
for year, numberlist in years.items():
    # iterate over the dict, find the mean of each list
    avgyears[year] = sum(numberlist) / len(numberlist)
    num = f"{avgyears[year]:.4f}".rstrip("0")
    print(f"{year}: {num}")
```

Comment: Thank you this works just fine, just one final question. How can is sort this print statement so i get the same order that i got with my initial results.

Comment: I figured it out  with this : for year, numberlist in sorted(years.items())

Thank you for the answers, i'm quite new to Python so i'm trying to learn it as best i can

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use pandas then

```
df = pd.read_csv("tv_show.txt", delimiter=";", header=None,
                 names=['name', 'year', 'rating'])
df = df.dropna()
df.groupby(['year'])['rating'].mean().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you keep a dictionary whose keys are years and values are lists of scores in that year? Populate the dict as you loop (dont forget to convert str to float). Then at the end you can just average each list.